# Just wanted to "confirm my hunch"

Tags: expressions

Someone replied to me with: "Just wanted to confirm my hunch."

What is this expression usually used for?

Answer (score 3):

In your example, **hunch** means a feeling that something is true or will happen, although you do not know any definite facts about it.[*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/hunch)

So, in your example, it's about confirming his feeling/instinct about something.

From the [Idioms section of Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hunch):

> **have a hunch** (that something is the case) and **have a hunch about
>   something**:
>
> to have an idea about what did, will,
>   or should happen; to have a feeling
>   that something will or should happen.
>
> *I had a hunch that you would be here when I arrived. I have a hunch about
>   the way things will happen.*

Comment: Quasimodo had a hunch.

Comment: about what ? ;)